# how to pass dynamic value from another table in mysql event

Tags: php, mysql

I want a insert reg_id into table which is present in another table where status=1 on every one minute

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
    D0
        BEGIN

        INSERT INTO article(title,description,useri_id)
        VALUES('a1ert', 'check check check',
        SELECT regid from users where uname ='admin');

    END |
DELIMITER ;
```

It says error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT reg_id from users where uname ='admin');
>         END' at line 6

Comment: Please add what you tried, what error you get and what you expect to do.

Comment: This looks like `phpmyadmin`, not PHP, nor codeigniter.

Comment: The issue is the subquery, this should be an `insert into...select`. I'm not going to transcribe an image though. Please add your query to the question. (I also see nothing about `status = 1` in your query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find solution describe below.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE STARTS '2017-08-01 09:37:14' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO 
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO article (title,description,user_id) SELECT 'alert','check check check',regid FROM user WHERE uname ='admin';

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Let me know if it not works.

Comment: it is useful only if there is one row in users table bt i have to fetch and insert all reg_id

Comment: Please check my updated answer, In question you did not mentioned that you need to insert all records.

Comment: thank you very much and sorry for incomplete question